# What is tolerance in region growing in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

**What does it mean by `tolerance` in the following code, and what is its effect on the image?**

What I understood is, this tolerance value can be from 0 to 255. If I use zero, the output image becomes totally black, and if I use 255, the output becomes totally white.

Why don't we always set its value to 127?

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35269-simple-single-seeded-region-growing

**segCroissRegion.m**

```
function Phi = segCroissRegion(input_image, x, y, tolerance)
    if(x == 0 || y == 0)
        imshow(input_image,[0 255]);
        [x,y] = ginput(1);
    end
    Phi = false(size(input_image,1),size(input_image,2));
    %ref = true(size(I,1),size(I,2));
    PhiOld = Phi;
    Phi(uint8(x),uint8(y)) = 1;

    while(sum(Phi(:)) ~= sum(PhiOld(:)))
        PhiOld = Phi;
        segm_val = input_image(Phi);
        meanSeg = mean(segm_val);
        posVoisinsPhi = imdilate(Phi,strel('disk',1,0)) - Phi;
        voisins = find(posVoisinsPhi);
        valeursVoisins = input_image(voisins);
        Phi(voisins(valeursVoisins > meanSeg - tolerance & valeursVoisins < meanSeg + tolerance)) = 1;
    end

    % Uncomment this if you only want to get the region boundaries
    % SE = strel('disk',1,0);
    % ImErd = imerode(Phi,SE);
    % Phi = Phi - ImErd;
end
```

**main.m**

```
overlaid_image = gray_imread('region_growing.png');
[x, y] = get_one_point_from_image(overlaid_image);
tolerance = 127;
Phi = segCroissRegion(overlaid_image, x, y, tolerance);
imshow(Phi);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm dilates the current region by one pixel. The value of each of these new pixels (candidate pixels) is then compared to the mean of the current region. If the value of a pixel is within the tolerance of the current mean it is added to the region, else discarded.

So the tolerance can be considered the maximum "step size" from the mean of the region to a new candidate pixel. Let's make and example:

Let's say we have an uint8 image, therefore its values can range from 0 to 255. The current mean of the region is 120, and the tolerance is 30. Then a candidate pixel is only added to the region if it's value is between between 90 and 150.

So if you set the tolerance to 0, a new pixel is only added if its value is *exactly* the same as the region mean - which is very unlikely! On the other hand, if you set the tolerance to 255 every pixel will be added because the values can't be outside the tolerance, no matter the mean.

Setting the tolerance to 127 would be a very high step size and therefore probably a bad idea. E.g. if the current mean is 100, then every candidate pixel between 0 to 227 would be added which probably would be almost every pixel.

This was all for an uint8 file. E.g. your image is stored as double, you have to use way higher tolerance values!